# How to set sessin timeout globally in spring java configuration

Tags: spring-mvc

Hi am trying to set session timeout globally for my whole spring mvc application. previously we configured session timeout in web.xml like  below

```
<web-app ...>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

How do i do this in spring java configuration??

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a `HttpSessionListener` listener:

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Session creation.");
        event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(1000);
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Session termination.");
    }
}
```

The method `setMaxInactiveInterval` takes seconds in input.

Comment: this is what I also did same take a look into my answer and loading session timeout from properties file is there any better way of loading properties file value

Answer (score 0):

You can load the value from the properties file as well

```
@Override
        public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
            try {
                ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
                InputStream stream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("bimspring.properties");
                Properties properties = new Properties();
                properties.load(stream);
                String sessionTimeout = properties.getProperty("sessionTimeout ", "No Value Found");
                event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(Integer.parseInt(sessionTimeout));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes, if you are in spring context (i.e: class is a spring bean) you can inject the value using the `@Value` annotation.

Comment: How to use @value in httplisetener class

Comment: Something like:`@Value("${bimspring.properties.sessionTimeout}") private Integer timeout;`